# Compass Watch Broken -- /watch_project.rb: cannot load such file -- fssm

Tags: rubygems, compass-sass

Compass watch worked fine for me previously, then all of a sudden, bang I get this error. Compass compile works fine. I tried reinstalling the gem, but I still get the same error.

```
LoadError on line ["70"] of /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb: cannot load such file -- fssm
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
will@will-System-Product-Name:/var/www/funandgames/angcomx/public$ compass watch --trace
LoadError on line ["70"] of /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb: cannot load such file -- fssm
  /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:70:in `perform'
  /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
  /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
  /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
  /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `call'
  /home/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
```

I tried gem install fssm, as well as a number of other proposed solutions online for similar errors, so far nothing has worked.

I am using ubuntu.

Comment: did you try installing fssm as sudo? that did if for me